# How to set .currentTime of HTMLMediaElement within canplay event, call play and avoid dispatching pause event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio, chromium

When setting `.currentTime` of `HTMLMediaElement` within `canplay` event before calling `.play()` the `pause` event is dispatched.

When trying to call `.play()` within `canplay` event after setting `.currentTime` and error is thrown

> `DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().`

How to set `.currentTime` within `canplay` or `canplaythrough` event of `HTMLMediaElement` without dispatching `pause` event, or how to call `.play()` from within `pause` event handler to commence media playback from the set `.currentTime`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <video preload="auto" controls></video>
  <span></span>
  <script>
    const url = "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=10,15";

    const video = document.querySelector("video");

    let cursor = 10.5;

    video.oncanplay = e => {
      video.oncanplay = null;
      video.currentTime = cursor;
      console.log(e, video.currentTime, video.buffered.end(0));
      video.play().catch(err => document.querySelector("span").textContent = err.message);
    }

    video.onpause = e => {
      console.log(e, video.currentTime);
    }

    video.src = url;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a really weird bug you've got there, I'm not sure where it comes from nor what were the odds you fall on it.

If I'm not mistaken, it would be that chrome doesn't honor the `src`'s timerange `#t=start,end` parameter anymore when you set the `currentTime` property.

So they will kind of forget it, and act as if you gone through the `end` threshold and thus pause the video.

But where it becomes really weird, is that when trying to write a test-case, I found out that this occurs only in the `canplay` event, only with this video, and only with the timerange set to `10,15`.

Set it to `#t=10.0,15`, *it works*.
Set it to `#t=10,15.0`, *it works*.
Set it to any other value, *it seems to work* <sub>(no I didn't tested **all** possible values)</sub>.
Set it to `#t=10,15` on an other video, *it works*.
Set it to `#t=10,15` on the same video, but served from an other server, *it **doesn't** work...*

```js
  // changed the #t parameter
  const url = "https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm#t=10.0,15";

    const video = document.querySelector("video");

    let cursor = 10.5;

    video.oncanplay = e => {
      video.oncanplay = null;
      video.currentTime = cursor;
      console.log(e, video.currentTime, video.buffered.end(0));
      video.play().catch(err => document.querySelector("span").textContent = err.message);
    }

    video.onpause = e => {
      console.log(e, video.currentTime);
    }

    video.src = url;
```

```html
  <video preload="auto" controls></video>
  <span></span>
```

So for a real fix, I think that https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/ is still the best way to go, but I'm not sure what they will tell you since this seems to be highly related with the video file itself.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've got *FFmpegVideoDecoder: avcodec_decode_video2(): Invalid data found when processing input, at timestamp: 10009000 duration: 41000 size: 502 side_data_size: 0 is_key_frame: 0 encrypted: 0 discard_padding (ms): (0, 0)*  in chrome://media-internals.

Comment: Chromium issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=767163